# Is it possible to show the `Explorer` tree in a different view in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Suppose I have a custom view in VSCode (which already has some tree views), is it possible to show the `Explorer` (`workbench.explorer.fileView`) tree in it?

Comment: do you know the id that is used to register the explorer View? Or it uses the VSC internal View API with extended capabilities

Comment: It seems to use the VSC internal API to register it.

Comment: What is its id and have you tried to add this to your own view container?

Comment: I tried to add it through the package.json and it complained saying that it already is defined elsewhere and the id is in the question (what I couldn't find out is if the way I tried is right -- from what I can tell I could only define new trees under the package.json and I couldn't find any API -- thus the question).